# Lazy loading csv with pandas

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have a huge 22 GB csv file that contains a matrix 10000 x 10000 entries. But actually I only need a small portion of file for my purpose that can fit well within my 4 GB ram.  Is there anyway to lazy load the CSV to my system so that I need to pick only some non contagious portion of the file say 25 different specific rows. I have heard of `iterator` in pandas that loads data piece by piece, but am still not sure of its memory requirements.

Comment: There are a number of options such as `nrows`, `chunksize`, `skiprows` which should do what you want, see the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-csv-table

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For a small number of lines try using [linecache](http://pymotw.com/2/linecache/) and manually creating a pandas DataFrame.

For example, the following code puts lines 12, 24, and 36 (1-indexed) into a DataFrame.

```
import linecache
from pandas import DataFrame

filename = "large.csv"
indices = [12,24,36]

li = []
for i in indices:
    li.append(linecache.getline(filename, i).rstrip().split(','))

dataframe = DataFrame(li)
```

Comment: You also need to perform type casting, as this solution only reads strings and puts them into the array.